# How to get total value of everything in a list with "$" on the values?

Tags: python

I would like to get the total value of everything in the list but as it is a str type and there is a $, i'm unable to convert it to a int or float.

I tried changing the type of the list but it resulted in an error. Is there any way to get the total value in the list

Comment: @marfcu I guess Ashish's question was whether `$` can come on either side of the `-` in negative numbers, or is it always on on left/right

Comment: `[float(s.replace('$', '')) for s in values]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[int(i.replace("$", "")) for i in l]` to remove the `$`

Or you can change the numbers to int by using `int(str[1:]) for str in list` (This is not perfect, since if the 1st letter is `-` it can cut that off, but i think the 1st item of your list is a typo :))

The `[1:]` Means slice off the 1st letter from the string, so the `$` will be gone and you can convert the str to a int by using `int()`

Comment: `'-$323'` will become `'$323'` which can't be converted to `int`

Comment: A regex or `str.replace('$', '')` is probably a better approach